# set security on Spring security on Spring roo

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-roo

In my application i want to set free acces to list and require authenticacion to the rest of the views of the reservas directory,this is my code

```
<intercept-url pattern="/reservas/list.jspx" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/reservas/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

and i've tried this

```
<intercept-url pattern="/reservas/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<intercept-url pattern="/reservas/list.jspx" access="permitAll" />
```

with the same result ,the application requires authentication for all the views.What i'm doing wrong with the URL's??

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `<intercept-url>` syntax is slightly different from using the security annotations.  Try this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/reservas/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
```

or, if you use "remember me" tokens, you would want:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/reservas/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED " />
```

Answer (score 0):

The  `/reservas/list.jspx` is not the URL for your "reservas" list view. Try to use `reservas`. The final URL is generated by the `@RequestMapping` annotation instead by de jspx view route:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/reservas" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/reservas/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

Also, you must check that all web resources used in you view doesn't requires authentication (by default the `resources/**`).